# Finding all-but-one matches

Tags: code-challenge, fastest-code

This challenge is about writing code to solve the following problem.

Given two strings A and B, your code should output the start and end indices of a substring of A with the following properties.

- The substring of A should also match some substring of B with up to one substitution of a single character in the string.
- There should be no longer substring of A that satisfies the first property.

For example:

```
A = xxxappleyyyyyyy

B = zapllezzz
```

The substring `apple` with indices `4 8` (indexing from 1) would be a valid output.

**Score**

The score of your answer will be the sum of length of your code in bytes + the time in seconds it takes on my computer when run on strings A and B of length 1 million each.

**Testing and input**

I will run your code on two strings of length 1 million taken from the strings in http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/chromosomes/

The input will be on standard in and will simply be two strings, separated by a new line.

**Languages and libraries**

You can use any language which has a freely available compiler/interpreter/etc. for Linux and any libraries which are also open source and freely available for Linux.

**My machine**
The timings will be run on my machine. This is a standard ubuntu install on an AMD FX-8350 Eight-Core Processor. This also means I need to be able to run your code. As a consequence, only use easily available free software and please include full instructions how to compile and run your code.

Comment: You need more absolute scoring definition. Running time on your computer doesn't sound like a good scoring method.

Comment: @mbomb007 It's the only sensible way to measure code speed and is the one always used in fastest code competitions on PPCG! People normally post their score on their own computer in their answer and wait for the OP to then produce a definitive score. It is 100% unambiguous at least.

Comment: @mbomb007 that is a very widely used scoring method for fastest code.

Comment: `if(hash(str1 == test1 && str2 == test2)) print("100,150") else ..` -- thoughts?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman  In the very unlikely event of a tie, the first answer wins.  `appley` needs two substitutions to match `apllez`. Maybe you missed that it is `apll` in B and not `appl` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## C++ time: O(n^2), extra space: O(1)

It takes 0.2s to complete the 15K data on my machine.

To compile it, use:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 code.cpp -o code
```

To run it, use:

```
./code < INPUT_FILE_THAT_CONTAINS_TWO_LINES_SPERATED_BY_A_LINE_BREAK
```

### Explaination

The idea is simple, for string `s1` and `s2`, we try to offset `s2` by `i`:

```
s1: abcabcabc
s2: bcabcab
```

When offset is 3:

```
s1: abcabcabc
s2:    bcabcab
```

Then, for each offset `i`, we perform a dynamic programing scan on `s1[i:]` and `s2`. For each `j`, let `f[j, 0]` be the maximum length `d` such that `s1[j - d:j] == s2[j - i - d: j - i]`. Similarly, let `f[j, 1]` be the maximum length `d` such that strings `s1[j - d:j]` and `s2[j - i - d:j - i]` differ by at most 1 character.

So for `s1[j] == s2[j - i]`, we have:

```
f[j, 0] = f[j - 1, 0] + 1  // concat solution in f[j - 1, 0] and s1[j]
f[j, 1] = f[j - 1, 1] + 1  // concat solution in f[j - 1, 1] and s1[j]
```

Otherwise:

```
f[j, 0] = 0  // the only choice is empty string
f[j, 1] = f[j - 1, 0] + 1  // concat solution in f[j - 1, 0] and s1[j] (or s2[j - i])
```

And:

```
f[-1, 0] = f[-1, 1] = 0
```

Since we only need f[j - 1, :] to calculate f[j, :], only O(1) extra space is used.

Finally, the max length will be:

```
max(f[j, 1] for all valid j and all i)
```

### Code

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1, s2;
    getline(cin, s1);
    getline(cin, s2);
    int n1, n2;
    n1 = s1.size();
    n2 = s2.size();
    int max_len = 0;
    int max_end = -1;
    for(int i = 1 - n2; i < n1; i++) {
        int f0, f1;
        int max_len2 = 0;
        int max_end2 = -1;
        f0 = f1 = 0;
        for(int j = max(i, 0), j_end = min(n1, i + n2); j < j_end; j++) {
            if(s1[j] == s2[j - i]) {
                f0 += 1;
                f1 += 1;
            } else {
                f1 = f0 + 1;
                f0 = 0;
            }
            if(f1 > max_len2) {
                max_len2 = f1;
                max_end2 = j + 1;
            }
        }
        if(max_len2 > max_len) {
            max_len = max_len2;
            max_end = max_end2;
        }
    }
    assert(max_end != -1);
    // cout << max_len << endl;
    cout << max_end - max_len + 1 << " " << max_end << endl;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been looking at the code and I can't find how it takes into account the possibility of strings matching except for one character, as in the example "apple" and "aplle". Could you explain?

Comment: @rcrmn That's what the dynamic programing part doing. To understand, it's helpful to try calculating the f[j, 0] and f[j, 1] manually for some simple cases. The previous code has some bugs so I updated the post.

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you think there might be an O(n log n) solution too?

Answer (score 2):

### C++

I tried thinking of a good algorithm to do this, but I'm a bit distracted today and couldn't think of anything that would work well. This runs at O(n^3) time, so it's veeeery slow. The other option I thought of could have been theoretically faster but would have taken O(n^2) space, and with inputs of 1M, it would have been worse even.

It's shameful, it takes 190 seconds for inputs of 15K. I'll try to improve it.
**Edit:** Added multiprocessing. Now takes 37 seconds for 15K input on 8 threads.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#undef cin
#undef cout
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> range;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    string a = "xxxappleyyyyyyy";
    string b = "zapllezzz";

    getline(cin, a);
    getline(cin, b);

    range longestA;
    range longestB;

    using namespace std::chrono;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    unsigned cores = thread::hardware_concurrency(); cores = cores > 0 ? cores : 1;

    cout << "Processing on " << cores << " cores." << endl;

    atomic<int> processedCount(0);

    vector<thread> threads;

    range* longestAs = new range[cores];
    range* longestBs = new range[cores];
    for (int t = 0; t < cores; ++t)
    {
        threads.push_back(thread([&processedCount, cores, t, &a, &b, &longestBs, &longestAs]()
        {
            int la = a.length();
            int l = la / cores + (t==cores-1? la % cores : 0);
            int lb = b.length();
            int aS = t*(la/cores);

            for (int i = aS; i < aS + l; ++i)
            {
                int count = processedCount.fetch_add(1);
                if ((count+1) * 100 / la > count * 100 / la)
                {
                    cout << (count+1) * 100 / la << "%" << endl;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < lb; ++j)
                {
                    range currentB = make_pair(j, j);
                    bool letterChanged = false;
                    for (int k = 0; k + j < lb && k + i < la; ++k)
                    {
                        if (a[i + k] == b[j + k])
                        {
                            currentB = make_pair(j, j + k);
                        }
                        else if (!letterChanged)
                        {
                            letterChanged = true;
                            currentB = make_pair(j, j + k);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (currentB.second - currentB.first > longestBs[t].second - longestBs[t].first)
                    {
                        longestBs[t] = currentB;
                        longestAs[t] = make_pair(i, i + currentB.second - currentB.first);
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    longestA = make_pair(0,0);
    for(int t = 0; t < cores; ++t)
    {
        threads[t].join();

        if (longestAs[t].second - longestAs[t].first > longestA.second - longestA.first)
        {
            longestA = longestAs[t];
            longestB = longestBs[t];
        }
    }

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);

    cout << "First substring at range (" << longestA.first << ", " << longestA.second << "):" << endl;
    cout << a.substr(longestA.first, longestA.second - longestA.first + 1) << endl;
    cout << "Second substring at range (" << longestB.first << ", " << longestB.second << "):" << endl;
    cout << b.substr(longestB.first, longestB.second - longestB.first + 1) << endl;
    cout << "It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds for input lengths " << a.length() << " and " << b.length() <<"." << endl;

    char c;
    cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry it's such a bad solution. I've been searching for an algorithm to accomplish this in better time, but didn't find anything for now...

Comment: Well, the complexity of the task required should be around O(n^4) to O(n^5), so long run times are a given

Comment: I believe it should be more like O(n^3) at worst case, at least with my algorithm it is. Anyway, I'm sure something can be done to improve it, like some kind of tree search, but I'm not sure how it would be implemented.

Comment: Oh yeah, O(n^3) it is... had a different approach in mind that would've taken O(n^4), but that one is kinda useless by now xD

Comment: you could save a small amount of time if you change the check in the two outer for loops from `i < a.length()` to `i < a.length - (longestA.second - longestA.first)` (same for j and b.length()) since you won't need to process any matches smaller than your current longest one

Comment: Maybe, but for 15K I found a longest match of only 40 characters, so it is a very small improvement. Thank you anyway, I'll take it into account when trying a new version.

Comment: Was the faster method dynamic programming? That could take O(n^2) time.

Comment: Yes, but a lot more memory than it would be manageable, the naive approach. I'll look for something that could simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](http://www.r-project.org/)

Seems I was over complicating the problem with the previous solution.  This is about 50% quicker (23 secs on 15k strings) than the previous one and pretty simple.

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
a="xxxappleyyyyyyy"
b="zapllezzz"
s=proc.time()
matchLen=1
matchIndex=1
indexA = 1
repeat {    
    i = 0
    repeat {
        srch = substring(a,indexA,indexA+matchLen+i)
        if (agrepl(srch,b,max.distance=list(insertions=0,deletions=0,substitutions=1)))
            i = i + 1
        else {
            if (i > 0) {
                matchLen = matchLen + i - 1
                matchIndex = indexA
            }
            break
        }
    }
    indexA=indexA+1
    if (indexA + matchLen > nchar(a)) break
}
c(matchIndex, matchLen + matchIndex)
print (substring(a,matchIndex, matchLen + matchIndex))
print(proc.time()-s)
```

This will never be a contender due to the language, but I did have a bit of fun doing it.
Not sure of the complexity of it, but over a couple of ~15k strings it takes 43 secs using a single thread.  The largest portion of that was the sorting of the arrays.  I tried some other libraries, but without significant improvement.

```
a="xxxappleyyyyyyy"
b="zapllezzz"
s=proc.time()
N=nchar
S=substring
U=unlist
V=strsplit
A=N(a)
B=N(b)
a=S(a,1:A)
b=S(b,1:B)
a=sort(a,method="quick")
b=sort(b,method="quick")
print(proc.time()-s)
C=D=1
E=X=Y=I=0
repeat{
    if(N(a[C])>E && N(b[D])>E){
        for(i in E:min(N(a[C]),N(b[D]))){
            if (sum(U(V(S(a[C],1,i),''))==U(V(S(b[D],1,i),'')))>i-2){
                F=i
            } else break
        }
        if (F>E) {
            X=A-N(a[C])+1
            Y=X+F-1
            E=F
        }
        if (a[C]<b[D])
            C=C+1
            else
            D=D+1
    } else
        if(S(a[C],1,1)<S(b[D],1,1))C=C+1 else D=D+1
    if(C>A||D>B)break
}
c(X,Y)
print(proc.time()-s)
```

**Method:**

- Create a suffix array for each string
- Order the suffix arrays
- Step through each of the arrays in a staggered sort of way comparing the beginning of each

Comment: Of course, the easiest solution in R is to use Bioconductor.

Comment: @archaephyrryx A bioconductor solution would be fun.

Comment: It would be ... But my quick read of the docs was way over my head.  Maybe if I understood the terms:-)

Comment: I deleted my first comment. You can of course use any open source library you like for this challenge.